# Python OpenPyxl trouble detecting all merged cells

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to detect all the merged cells in a *openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet* object and it seems that the *merged_cells.ranges* cannot all the merged cells but merged cells in some columns. My goal is to detect the merged cells, unmerge them and then remerge certain cells based on column values. During unmerging, I fill the unmerged cells with the top-left cell value of the merged cell.

I have worked around with this problem by filling nan in cells which are supposed to be recognized as a merged cell with previous value in the column since all my merged cells range in the same column, for example A18:A19, B18:B19. But things have become more tricky after I updated my xlsx file. OpenPyxl didn't find merged cells in A, C and E columns in my previous xlsx. Now it has trouble finding merged cells in B, D and F columns. Two xlsx file has the same format but different data.

Here is an example of what my xlsx looks like:
[xlsx sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBBcZ.png)

My code to read the xlsx then detect & unmerge the merged cells:

```
client_info_wb = load_workbook(path_client_info)
sheet_name = client_info_wb.sheetnames[0]
client_info_ws = client_info_wb[sheet_name]

for cell_group in client_info_ws.merged_cells.ranges:
    print(cell_group)
    min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = range_boundaries(str(cell_group))
    top_left_cell_value = client_info_ws.cell(row=min_row, column=min_col).value
    print(top_left_cell_value)
    client_info_ws.unmerge_cells(str(cell_group))
    for row in client_info_ws.iter_rows(min_col=min_col, min_row=min_row, max_col=max_col, max_row=max_row):
        for cell in row:
            cell.value = top_left_cell_value
```

Output for `print(cell_group)`:

```
A48:A49
2021-01-05
C48:C49
XX5614
E48:E49
ID
A46:A47
2021-01-05
C46:C47
XX2134
E46:E47
ID
A44:A45
2021-01-05
C44:C45
XX1234
E44:E45
ID
```

The information in those columns where openpyxl merged_cells.ranges fails to detect merged cells is necessary to the following operations in my code. So can anyone help me with this? Are there anyone having the same issue? I have spent a long time trying to find the patterns in my xlsx to find out what is causing the trouble and had no luck.

Answer (score 1):

```py
    while sheet.merged_cells: # <- Here's the change to make.
        for cell_group in sheet.merged_cells:
            val = str(cell_group.start_cell.value).strip()
            sheet.unmerge_cells(str(cell_group))
            for merged_cell in cell_group.cells:
                sheet.cell(row=merged_cell[0], column=merged_cell[1]).value = val
```

It seems like the set of merged_cells changes as it is iterated over, so repeating the loop until `merged_cells` is `None` does the trick.

There's also something weird going on with the in-memory buffer, so I save the file to disk and reload it with pandas, rather than loading the dataframe from the sheet in memory. (This could easily be optimized with a BytesIO object.)

For me, this guarantees that all merged cells are unmerged and replaced with the start cell's value.

Comment: your workaround helped hugely. Thanks for sharing